# Send message from server-side(Java) to Facebook users

Tags: java, facebook, server-side

I've a site that performs a lot of processings asynchronously, and in certain moments, should  to send private messages to users that previously have installed the Facebook app of my site.

Is it possible to send messages from server-side (Java) directly to these users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, if it was, imagine the amount of spam Facebook users would be receiving.

Alternatively, you can access their emails (with the appropriate permission), and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Soufiane Hassou. Was what I had imagined ;)